# Way to get rid of null from unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm getting NPE with `url` variable in method when trying to concat this url (which is resolved as a null with `givenTitle`).

```
package bookstore.scraper.book.booksource.empik;

import bookstore.scraper.book.Book;
import bookstore.scraper.book.booksource.BookServiceSource;
import bookstore.scraper.enums.Bookstore;
import bookstore.scraper.enums.CategoryType;
import bookstore.scraper.urlproperties.EmpikUrlProperties;
import bookstore.scraper.utilities.JSoupConnector;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@Service
public class EmpikSource implements BookServiceSource {

    private static final int FIRST_PART_PRICE = 0;
    private static final int SECOND_PART_PRICE = 1;

    private static final int BESTSELLERS_NUMBER_TO_FETCH = 5;
    private static final int CATEGORIZED_BOOKS_NUMBER_TO_FETCH = 15;
    private static final String DIV_PRODUCT_WRAPPER = "div.productWrapper";
    private static final String DATA_PRODUCT_ID = "data-product-id";

    private final EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties;
    private final JSoupConnector jSoupConnector;
    private Map<CategoryType, String> categoryToEmpikURL;

    @Autowired
    public EmpikSource(EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties, JSoupConnector jSoupConnector) {
        this.empikUrlProperties = empikUrlProperties;
        this.jSoupConnector = jSoupConnector;
        categoryToEmpikURL = createCategoryToEmpikURLMap();
    }

    @Override
    public Bookstore getName() {
        return Bookstore.EMPIK;
    }


    @Override
    public Book getMostPreciseBook(String givenTitle) {
        String concatedUrl = concatUrlWithTitle(categoryToEmpikURL.get(CategoryType.MOST_PRECISE_BOOK), givenTitle);

        Document document = jSoupConnector.connect(concatedUrl);

        String author = document.select("div.smartAuthorWrapper.ta-product-smartauthor").select("a").first().text();
        String price = convertEmpikPriceWithPossibleDiscountToActualPrice(document.select("div.price.ta-price-tile").first().text());
        String title = document.select(DIV_PRODUCT_WRAPPER).select("strong").first().text();
        String productID = document.select(DIV_PRODUCT_WRAPPER).select("a").first().attr(DATA_PRODUCT_ID);
        String bookUrl = createBookURL(title, productID);

        return Book.builder()
                .author(author)
                .price(price)
                .title(title)
                .productID(productID)
                .bookURL(bookUrl).build();
    }

    private String concatUrlWithTitle(String url, String title) {
        return String.format(url, title);
    }
private Map<CategoryType, String> createCategoryToEmpikURLMap() {
        Map<CategoryType, String> map = new EnumMap<>(CategoryType.class);

        map.put(CategoryType.CRIME, empikUrlProperties.getCrime());
        map.put(CategoryType.BESTSELLER, empikUrlProperties.getBestSellers());
        map.put(CategoryType.BIOGRAPHY, empikUrlProperties.getBiographies());
        map.put(CategoryType.FANTASY, empikUrlProperties.getFantasy());
        map.put(CategoryType.GUIDES, empikUrlProperties.getGuides());
        map.put(CategoryType.MOST_PRECISE_BOOK, empikUrlProperties.getMostPreciseBook());
        map.put(CategoryType.ROMANCES, empikUrlProperties.getRomances());

        return map;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
package bookstore.scraper.book.booksource.empik;

import bookstore.scraper.book.Book;
import bookstore.scraper.enums.CategoryType;
import bookstore.scraper.urlproperties.EmpikUrlProperties;
import bookstore.scraper.utilities.JSoupConnector;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.List;

import static bookstore.scraper.dataprovider.EmpikBookProvider.prepare15CrimeBooks;
import static bookstore.scraper.dataprovider.EmpikBookProvider.prepareMostPreciseBook;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmpikSourceTest {

    @Mock
    JSoupConnector jSoupConnector;
    @Mock
    EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties;

    @InjectMocks
    EmpikSource empikSource;

    /*@Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(empikUrlProperties.getConcreteBook()).thenReturn(anyString());
    }
*/

    @Test
    public void getMostPreciseBook() throws IOException {
        File in = getFile("/empik/MostPreciseBookEmpik.html");
        Document empikDocument = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8");

        when(jSoupConnector.connect(any())).thenReturn(empikDocument);
        when(empikUrlProperties.getConcreteBook()).thenReturn("https://www.empik.com/%s,%s,ksiazka-p");

        Book actualBooks = empikSource.getMostPreciseBook("W pustyni i w puszczy. Lektura z opracowaniem - Henryk Sienkiewicz");
        Book expectedBooks = prepareMostPreciseBook();

        assertEquals(expectedBooks, actualBooks);
    }

    private File getFile(String resourceName) {
        try {
            return new File(EmpikSourceTest.class.getResource(resourceName).toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

What should I do not to have url as a null?

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1769)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2698)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2653)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2607)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2734)
    at bookstore.scraper.book.booksource.empik.EmpikSource.concatUrlWithTitle(EmpikSource.java:154)
    at bookstore.scraper.book.booksource.empik.EmpikSource.getMostPreciseBook(EmpikSource.java:74)
    at bookstore.scraper.book.booksource.empik.EmpikSourceTest.getMostPreciseBook(EmpikSourceTest.java:66)
```

EmpikUrlProperties:

```
package bookstore.scraper.urlproperties;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("external.library.url.empik")
public class EmpikUrlProperties {

    private String mostPreciseBook;
    private String bestSellers;
    private String concreteBook;
    private String romances;
    private String biographies;
    private String crime;
    private String guides;
    private String fantasy;
}
```

Comment: The null url comes from the Map categoryToEmpikURL. This Map is created by the method createCategoryToEmpikURLMap(). But you didn't post tat method.

Comment: @JBNizet Ye, but this method is private as I dont need to is it outside. I was thinking about some workaround, but didn't come up with any good idea. Should I change it for public?

Comment: @JBNizet ahh sorry. Misunderstood your comment. I've already added this method.

Comment: So, again, you need to look at what your code is doing. It's populated the map, inside the constructor, with values coming from the properties. The properties are a constructor argument. When is that constructor called in your test? It's called by Mockito, due to the InjectMocks annotation. What is passed as argument? A mock. Mocks return null by default. So the constructor stores null values in the map. I would remove that map which is useless, and get values from the properties directly. This way, you can tell your mock what to return before calling the method under test.

Comment: Or better, not even use a mock for the properties, since it's a POJO that you can just populate yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet I cannot remove Map as it is needed. Whole class looks like this https://gist.github.com/must1/3f412fc8fdb165719e0c07c30c66ac24 so as you can see this map is needed for `getBooksByCategory` method as categoryType is passed via arguments list. Then why line `when(empikUrlProperties.getConcreteBook()).thenReturn("https://www.empik.com/%s,%s,ksiazka-p");` does not work. I set beahviour for this property.

Comment: @second What do you mean?

Comment: @second The first sentence is totally incomprehensible for me. I do not know how empikUrlPropeties should look then, cuz If I can simplify the code of course I would do it, but do not know how.

Comment: @second 'Or if you really want to use the map, you can just pass it as another constructor parameter' create new constructor without `@Autowired` annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

Add a new method `getCategory` to `empikUrlProperties`.

```java
public String getCategory(CategoryType category) {
    assert (category != null);

    switch (category) {
        case CategoryType.CRIME:
            return getCrime();
        case CategoryType.BESTSELLER:
            return getBestSellers();
        case CategoryType.BIOGRAPHY:
            return getBiographies();
        case CategoryType.FANTASY:
            return getFantasy();
        case CategoryType.GUIDES:
            return getGuides();
        case CategoryType.MOST_PRECISE_BOOK:
            return getMostPreciseBook();
        case CategoryType.ROMANCES:
            return getRomances();
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected category: " + category)
    }
}
```

for the test now you simply mock it

```java
when(empikUrlProperties.getCategory(CategoryType.CRIME))
    .thenReturn("https://www.empik.com/%s,%s,ksiazka-p");
```

---

Option 2:

Change your constructor to accept the map from outside.
This would imply you move the map creation to another class/function,
which creates the map elsewhere.

In this case you would need to inject your mock manually (don't use `@InjectMocks`),
as you should not mock a collection.

(For this part I am not sure how the @Autowired would handle it, maybe you need to wrap it into another class. A setter might be a more appropriate option.)

```java
@Autowired
public EmpikSource(EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties, JSoupConnector jSoupConnector, Map<CategoryType, String> categoryToEmpikURL ) {
    this.empikUrlProperties = empikUrlProperties;
    this.jSoupConnector = jSoupConnector;
    categoryToEmpikURL = categoryToEmpikURL;
}
```

Comment: If someone with more `spring` knowledge can add how to do handle the map together with `@Autowired` feel free to edit the answer or add some comment.

Comment: Okay, but I have got one question. I added your line with given URL, but when I replaced it with anyString() then I got exception about `Invalid use of argument matchers!` `This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
` Why is it throwing the exception here, but not with `when(empikUrlProperties.getConcreteBook()).thenReturn(anyString());` line?

Comment: `anyString()` is only to be used as an argument to a mocked function (it is an `argumentmatcher`). You have to specify a real value that you want to return.

Comment: I dont get it. Both functions are from the same class `when(empikUrlProperties.getCategory(CategoryType.MOST_PRECISE_BOOK)).thenReturn("https://www.empik.com/,%s,ksiazka-p");
when(empikUrlProperties.getConcreteBook()).thenReturn(anyString());`

Comment: and in first I cannot use anyString in second I can use it.

Comment: If you look at the implementation of `ArgumentMatchers.anyString()` you will see that it returns an empty string. However that is probably not what you want to return. -- The exception actually comes from how Mockito internally works and verifies that it is correctly used. So in some cases you get an exception, in other not (because mockito can not detect it).

Comment: Then, should I use `anyString` or not?

Comment: If you're interested in it feel free to open up another question, something a long the lines of: Why should I not use anyString() in my thenReturn( ... ). I see that usage here way to often, but a more detailed explanation is beyond the comment section. (I haven't found one, but maybe there is already one around here somewhere)

Comment: You should not. The only valid use is for matching arguments.